# 13inch MacBook Pro M2 battery not charging fully

Tags: macbook-pro

My 13inch MacBook Pro 2 has not been charging properly, sometimes it doesn't charge, sometimes only to 50%.

My battery health it at 95% and it does have water damage (water trapped in screen) But this has been happening since before then

Comment: Your last paragraph  - to what are you referring to, the battery or your MacBook Pro.  As for the timeframe, did you drop or injure your Mac in any way prior to your event or your b-day?

Comment: How did the "water damage" occur? Ultimately, this sounds like a hardware problem that will require physical fixing, probably with some parts needing replacement. If you spilt water on the keyboard, then it will make its way to the battery.

Comment: the water is in the mac screen but it was happening before this, it does have some dents in it (straight from being delivered) and the corners are chipped off

Comment: If a dented MBP was delivered to me, I would send it back; unless it was secondhand and the price had been lowered accordingly.  Physical shock can affect the internal components, including the battery. Sounds like this laptop has been in the wars, and needs some love. Take it to an Apple Store, and see what they say needs fixing.